# modify fixture data in cypress and intercept it

Tags: javascript, cypress

let say I have this setting.json

```
{ data: { isDark: false } }
```

and I intercept it like so

```
cy.intercept("api/setting", {
    fixture: `setting.json`,
 })
```

it worked.

But there's no way I want to create one file for one new property in the setting.json or when isDark is true. So how can I change the property values of the setting.json in my test?

I tried

```
cy.intercept("api/setting", (req) => {
 const settingFixture = await cy.fixture('setting.json')

 req.continue((res) => {
  res.send(settingFixture.map((object)=>({...object, isDark: true}))
 })

 cy.visit('some where')
})
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think part of your answer in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlLLi5N4h78, check it out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Cypress documentation about **fixture** command (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Modifying-fixture-data-before-using-it),
I think you can try something like this:

```
cy.fixture('setting.json').then(settingFixture => {
    
    // Update your JSON object according to your context
    // ...

    // Stub your response with this JSON object updated
    cy.intercept("api/setting", settingFixture)
});


// Navigate to your URL
cy.visit('some where')
```